# Set a string as a var after selecting a UITableView cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am making an audio app, and I am populating a table view controller with data from JSON. Based on the user's selection, I want to pass the `episode_name`, shown in the cell, into the next view after segue.

So far, the table loads with data, I can pass a locally defined variable to the next view, but I can't **copy** the string from the cell into that variable.

Here's my code.

```
func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{
  //... removed to condense 
    if let shows_list = json as? NSArray
    {
        for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
        {
            if let shows_obj = shows_list[i] as? NSDictionary
            {
                let episode_name = shows_obj["episode"] as? String
                let episode_date = shows_obj["date"] as? String
                TableData.append(episode_date! + " | " + episode_name!)
            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {self.do_table_refresh()})

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "passer", sender: indexPath)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "passer" {

            let vc = segue.destination as! EpisodeViewController
            vc.variableInSecondVc = "Pass Variable" // this is where I want to pass episode_name

    }

} // end segue
```

Solutions I have tried:
1) if I call episode_name immediately, it flags it because that variable is contained in the prior function,
2) if I try to run the `extract_json` function in the ViewDidLoad, it's causing other issues in the code.

I'm new to Swift and unsure -- is there a better way to "copy" the string from that cell and pass it to the `vc.variableInSecondVc`?

EDIT: One point of clarification. If I ran this code, it would successfully change the subsequent `UILabel` to "Pass Variable" -- but of course, I actually want to turn `PassVariable` dynamic by changing it to reflect the string of `episode_name`.

Answer (score 1):

The `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` method takes two arguments, 1. The Segue identifier, 2. The parameter you want to pass of type AnyObject?

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "passer", sender: indexPath)
```

In the `prepare(for:sender:)` method, you check the segue identifier and cast the sender parameter to the type you had passed earlier, and get data from the array list to pass it to next view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "passer" {
        guard let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }

        let data = TableData[indexPath.row] //write your logic here to get value from your data list based on index path row value and pass value to view controller.

        let vc = segue.destination as! EpisodeViewController
        vc.variableInSecondVc = data //value which you got from list based on indexPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not passing the value. I confirmed it's not in the 2nd VC -- I removed the indexPath code and substituted a static value like "="testing"" and it updates the second VC. I am thinking there may be an issue with indexPath.row transmitting the string, but I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: Actually, update. It's really weird. I added a print in the function above for data, and it does correctly print the row's value when I hit the segue. It doesn't apply to the label though, even when it worked statically before I changed it to reflect the cell's value.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. Can you post your full code of both view controller. The code solution I gave will work as it will get the data and sent to next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will send the selected string to next View controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "passer" , let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath{
        let vc = segue.destination as! EpisodeViewController
        vc.variableInSecondVc = TableData[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried. No errors, but it doesn't load in the next view controller (screen is blank). Will do some testing. The variable is a string, so maybe that's it: `    var variableInSecondVc = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Get data from indexPath

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "passer" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! EpisodeViewController
        vc.variableInSecondVc = TableData[indexPath.row]
    }

}
```

And carefully, you should get the string in viewDidAppear in secondViewController

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    label.text = variableInSecondVc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, all.

While these solutions didn't work, they helped me rethink the problem, and I found a solution that will pass the value to the label in the next VC successfully. Here's the approach:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "passer", sender: indexPath)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let controller = segue.destination as! EpisodeViewController
                controller.variableInSecondVc = TableData[indexPath.row]
            }
    }
```

The label now updates in the next view controller.

Comment: That's a bad solution. `indexPathForSelectedRow` is pointless because the index path is already in the `sender` parameter. Alok's answer is supposed to work.